# Promise.all not waiting for array.map to resolve

Tags: node.js

I have a map that I have created but Promise.all is not waiting for the map to resolve before continuing.

```
const newMessage = async (params) => {
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('sending')
    sqs.sendMessage(params, function (err, data){
        if (err){
            console.error(err);
            reject(err);
        }
        console.log('Sent')
        resolve(data);
    }).promise();
}).then((data => {
    return data;
}));
};

const promise = messageData.map(newMessage);
await Promise.all(promise);
```

There is a part beforehand that adds all the required params into the array.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right way to use `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up `await` and `then` and just return `new Promise`:

```
const newMessage = async (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('sending')
    sqs.sendMessage(params, function (err, data){
        if (err){
            console.error(err);
            reject(err);
        }
        console.log('Sent')
        resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: okay so just tested it and the await Promis.all still continues, I don't event get the 'sending' in console.

Comment: I removed `await`, sorry

Comment: Still the same unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure `messageData` is not an empty array?